# Can't match route after rewriting target using Traefik IngressRoute for an Angular Service

Tags: angular, kubernetes, angular2-routing, traefik, traefik-ingress

I've build a super simple Angular Application which just displays "Ok" when accessed on the main path.
This is the deployment descriptor for it:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: meal-planner-fe
  namespace: home
  labels:
    app: meal-planner-fe
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: meal-planner-fe
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30000
      name: meal-planner-fe
---
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: meal-planner-fe
  namespace: home
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: meal-planner-fe
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: meal-planner-fe
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: meal-planner-fe
          image: 08021986/meal-planner-fe:v1
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```

When I port-forward the service using `kubectl port-forward -h home svc/meal-planner-fe 80:80` and access `http://localhost` it works as intended.

I'm now trying to build an IngressRoute using Traefik 2.0 which exposes the service to the outside without using port-forwarding.

This is my IngressRoute descriptor:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: prefix-stripper
  namespace: home
spec:
  stripPrefix:
    prefixes:
      - /web
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: meal-planner-ingress
  namespace: home
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
    - host: urr4.me
      match: PathPrefix(`/web`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: meal-planner-fe
          port: 80
      middlewares:
        - name: prefix-stripper
          namepsace: home
```

I use the Middleware to strip the URL of `/web` since I want to access the Angular app on the base-path.
When I now open `http://urr4.me/web`, it rewrites the URL as intended to `http://urr4.me`, but the Application still complains, that /web doesn't match any routes.
[image: See here]

I don't know if I missunderstood. What I want is an Ingress that allows to open `http://urr4.me/web` from outside the cluster and obtain the same as if opening `http://localhost` when using the port-forwarding as mentioned above.

I have currently added urr4.me to my hosts file using the ip of the master node.

Comment: How did you setup your Kubernetes cluster (`kubeadm`, `minikube`, cloud solution etc..) ? For which architecture did you create your Docker image -> I tried to run it on my cluster but I have an error (`standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error`, output of the `kubectl logs {pod-name}` ) ?

Comment: Im running it on a Raspberry Pi cluster, initialized using K3s. The image is build for arm32/v7 architecture.